# Simplifying an equation by factoring the current coefficients in order to substitute a new coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have an equation in the following form:

```
a*x + b*y + c*z == d
```

I want to substitute the following constants instead of a,b,c,d:

```
e=a/d
f=b/d
g=c/d
```

To simplify the equation in the following form:

```
e*x + f*y + g*z == 1
```

How can I simplify the equations with these kind of substitutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = a*x + b*y + c*z == d;
```

Using [`Eliminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html)

```
Assuming[{x != 0, y != 0, z != 0},
 Eliminate[{eqn, e == a/d, f == b/d, g == c/d},
   {a, b, c, d}] // Simplify]

(* e x + f y + g z == 1 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = a*x + b*y + c*z == d
Simplify[eq /. {a -> e d, b -> f d, c -> g d}, d != 0]
(* e x + f y + g z == 1 *)
```

Comment: I want to exactly use the definitions e = a/d, f=b/d, and g=c/d.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With[{a = e d, b = f d,c = g d}, eq = a*x + b*y + c*z == d; Map[PolynomialQuotient[#, eq[[2]], x] &, eq]]
(*e x + f y + g z == 1*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you literally wish to use `{e == a/d, f == b/d, g == c/d}`, this also works.

```
Expand[#/d & /@ (a*x + b*y + c*z == d)] /. 
    (Reverse /@ {e == a/d, f == b/d, g == c/d} /. Equal -> Rule)
(* e x + f y + g z == 1 *)
```